# iCarousel two different transition times

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, carousel

I'm currently using iCarousel for displaying my images in my apps, which works perfectly. A few days ago I downloaded the new Jamie Oliver recipes iPad app and there's an awesome carousel with pictures and a text. Both of them are a carousel but they have different transition times and this just looks amazing. I tried some things but I didn't find a solution.
Does anyone know if this is possible with iCarousel or how did they make this?

Would be great if someone could maybe download the app and tell me what he thinks about this and how it can be made.

Thank you!!

Comment: iCarousel has a property called scrollSpeed.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I tried it it's how many items you can scroll with one scroll, what I'm looking for is a property how fast/slow the next item appears (this stays with scrollSpeed always the same)

Comment: I have used iCarousel quite often, however I am not clear with your question about the speed as I could not download this app due to some reasons. If you can post a video of the animation, I can help you out.